# Post relationships/nesting

Tags: posts, customization

Ok, I know that posts can't be nested but for the purpose of this question, I'm using the word.

I'm having some trouble wrapping my head around creating a pedigree site, I'll explain where I am and where I'm stuck.

So far I just have the CPT and custom fields created with the ACF plugin.

I created a number of posts placed in taxonomies, see below;

- Posts: Farther, Mother | Placed in tax Parents
- Posts: Son, Daughter, Daughter | Placed in tax Children
- Posts: Grandson, Granddaughter, Grandson, Granddaughter  | Placed in tax Grandchildren
- Posts: Great grandson, Great granddaughter, Great grandson, Great granddaughter, Great grandson, Great granddaughter  | Placed in tax Great-grandchildren

So I need to create a relationship between these posts and output that relationship to an archive type page that I'll format in a tree view.

My question is how do you create that relationship and output it?

I hope I explained correctly, if clarification is needed please let me know.

Comment: You can do relationships with ACFs, have you looked at using these?

Comment: You can do hierarchical post types, if that helps. But what are you trying to do, exactly? Your custom post type item `Father` could have a child post item `daughter`, and there would be a direct relationship w/o the need for any plugins.

Comment: Aravona I have looked at the ACF relationships yes. @Michael what I'm trying to figure out is I guess assigning the post, for example, I create a post that I place in **Father** I then create another post that goes into **daughter** how do I then assign that post to that particular Father post? Hell I hope I explained that one right :P

Comment: In this case I'm not sure why you mention your taxonomy, because it has nothing to do with creating this kind of relationship. As I said, you can use hierarchy or you could use ACF relationships, which does pretty much what you want, I suppose.

Comment: Ah ok, thanks very much @Michael, appreciate the input.